# UMBRACO cshtml display data from microsoft SQL server table

Tags: c#, content-management-system, umbraco

I have inherited an Umbraco 4.9 site and need to display some data from an SQL database.
I have created a macro using a cshtml file but it keeps failing on the creation of the sqldataconnection.

Here is the code.

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@using System.Xml.Linq
@using System.Text
@using System.Data
@using System.Data.SqlClient

@{
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [mydb] ");

}

<div class="park-list">
<h2>Parking List</h2>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: when the page displays I get most of the page with this. Error loading MacroEngine script (file:

Comment: I assume the ConnectionString above is a real connection string from the web.config?

Comment: yes and I've tested the connectionstring with a user control and it works.

Comment: I would suggest adding a ?umbDebugShowTrace=true to your query string in order to view details of the exception. This will require you to have the umbracoDebugMode app setting in your Web.config
 set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a helper class or library and call that from the razor script.  You could simply add the class to the App_Code directory or create a new project locally and upload the dll.

That said, you could use something lightweight like PetaPoco: https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/blob/master/PetaPoco/PetaPoco.cs.  Add that file to your App_Code and then something like this might work:

```
@{
   var myDb = new PetaPoco.Database(connectionstringfromwebconfig);
   var someResult = myDb.Fetch("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn=@0", "Some value");
} 

<ul>
@foreach(var row in someResult)
{
 <li>
 @row.SomeOtherColumn 
 </li>
}
</ul>
```

I found this code here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/31685-Razor-ans-SQL-commands and there is other code that may help at the bottom of the thread.

Comment: I have played around with this and its expecting something in the "Some Value"  but I have no idea what that is. Do you have any idea what this might be?

Comment: That SQL is just example SQL.  The "Some Value" is just whatever you want to filter "SomeColumn" by.

Comment: I was able to get the original code to work, there was a firewall issue blocking access from that server to the sql server.